# How to properly extract inner text from a table value within a webpage with vba?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

Unfortunately my old account got deleted when changing website hosts. I looked throughout the site for a solution but only found people dealing with entire tables rather than just trying to obtain one value. I am having an issue grabbing Net Assets with innerText from the following webpage:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UMBWX?p=UMBWX

Here is my attempt:

```
Sub FetchAssets()
Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, URL As String

    URL = https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UMBWX?p=UMBWX
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

            .Open "GET", URL, False
            Application.Wait Now + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60# * 2)
            .send
            Application.Wait Now + 1 / (24 * 60 * 60# * 2)
            HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
            
            Set elem = HTML.querySelector("NET_ASSETS-value")
            MsgBox elem.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

This attempt results in: `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

I have tried the exact same code and swapped `elem.innerText` with `elem.innerHTML` and it results in the same error. The error happens on the MsgBox line of code, it sets elem fine.

Due to my reputation being under 10 I can not embed an image, but here is the line of code from the webpage:

```
<td class="Ta(end) Fw(600) Lh(14px)" data-test="NET_ASSETS-value" data-reactid="89"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) " data-reactid="90">539.25M</span></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub FetchAssets()
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, elem As Object, sURL As String
    sURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UMBWX?p=UMBWX"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Set elem = html.querySelector("td[data-test='NET_ASSETS-value']")
        MsgBox elem.innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know why this ticker is pulling through an N/A but when I try VTSAX it pulls through the value? The code has the net asset value so I am not sure why it would pull an N/A?